# Laravel join results Column product_id in field list is ambigous error

Tags: php, laravel, join

Laravel join results Column product_id in field list is ambigous error.

Here is my code:

```php
$selectspecification=DB::table('product')
    ->whereIn('product.product_id',$productid)
    ->join('detail','detail.id','product.id')
    ->join('specification','specification.specification_id','product.specific_id')
    
    ->join('tbl_products','tbl_products.product_id', '=' ,'tbl_product_spec.product_id')
    
    ->select('name','specification_name','product_id','spec_id')
        ->where('tbl_product_spec.product_spec_status',0)
        ->where('tbl_products.added_by',$seller_id)
            ->groupBy('tbl_specific_detail.specific_id')
            ->groupBy('tbl_product_spec.product_spec_detail_id')
        
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `table` name with `product_id`.. `tbl_specific_detail.product_id`

```
->select('tbl_specific_detail.specific_detail_name','tbl_specification.specification_name',
 'tbl_specific_detail.product_id','tbl_specific_detail.specific_id')
```